# Group Item: cannot install file to same location

Tags: qbs

In my project, I have several plugins depending on a single module, containing a `Group` item similar to:

```qml
Group {
    name: "group"
    qbs.install: true
    qbs.installDir: "../"
    files: <filename>
}
```

But compilation fails with "error: Cannot install files '*filename*' and '*filename*' to the same location '*location*'". Basically, qbs cannot copy same file to same location twice (seems illogical to me)

How can this bug be resolved or is there any elegant workaround?

Comment: how do you add the dependency to the module in the other Products ?

Comment: @BlueMagma, in every product dependency on the module is specified as `Depends { name: "MyModuleName" }`

Comment: can you provide the full Module (or is it confidential) ?

Comment: @BlueMagma, I'm not sure, but it is most likely confidential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround, which may require some restructuring of a project:

instead of:

```
Module {
    name: "somemodule"

    // module properties set to dependant products

    Group {
        // files to install
        qbs.install: true
    }
}
```

we can use:

```
Product {
    name: "somemodule"

    Group {
        // files to install
        qbs.install: true
    }

    Export { 
        // module properties set to dependant products
    }
}
```

This way, files are only installed once when steps for `mymodule` are run, thus eliminating the conflict. Module properties, exported via `Export` Item, work just as ones exported via `Module`.

Limitations:

1. `Product` has to be added to `references` of the `Project` Item
2. `Modules` cannot depend on `Product` Items, which may require to restructure all dependant modules into `Project`/`Export` pairs too

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the `qbs.installSourceBase` property. Basically, you set this to the base directory containing the files in your Group, and Qbs will install the listed files into `qbs.installDir` hierarchically based on their paths relative to the aforementioned base directory.

For example, given the following Group:

```qml
// defined in /source/myproject/myproject.qbs
Group {
    qbs.install: true
    qbs.installDir: "share/stuff"
    qbs.installSourceBase: "." // relative to /source/myproject
    files: [
        "fileA.txt",
        "fileB.txt",
        "subdir/fileB.txt",
    ]
}
```

and the following command line invocation:

```
$ qbs [...] --install-root /sample/some-root
```

the following filesystem hierarchy will result:

```
/sample/some-root/share/stuff/fileA.txt
/sample/some-root/share/stuff/fileB.txt
/sample/some-root/share/stuff/subdir/fileB.txt
```

See the Qbs [Installation Properties](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/qbs-module.html#installation-properties) documentation for more info.

Comment: it doesn't resolve issue with inability to install same file to same location from two subprojects...

Comment: That's a logical paradox - you cannot install two different files to the same path. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to copy one file to one location, but from two subprojects.

Comment: So you have several products which depend on a Module that contains a Group? That doesn't sound right; generally you should not have a Group in a Module. Perhaps you could use a product instead? Additional context about your project structure would be helpful.